# Losing Session on AJAX request only on IE8 hitting Server 2003

Tags: c#, ajax, internet-explorer-8, windows-server-2003

OK, so we're having a problem with one part of our web application, where the Session is being lost when we hit an AJAX handler (.ashx) from javascript using jQuery to make the call.

This is, however only happening under kind of specific circumstances: the hosting machines are running **Server 2003 with IIS 6.0** and the clients are using **IE8**. The IE8 clients can hit a **Server 2008 machine with IIS 7** and it works AND the **IE9** clients can hit the **Server 2003 machines** and it works (the IE9 clients work with either type of host).

We are running debuggable and precompiled versions of the site and the results remain consistent for both. I have the .ashx class implementing `IRequiresSessionState` (we also tried IReadOnlySessionState and it didn't work).

The part of our app where this is happening is also in a virtual directory of our main application.

We've been messing around with this quite a bit and haven't been able to resolve this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Press F-12 to open the debugger, look at the NET tab and watch your request/response.

Comment: @Diodeus Both browsers have the ASP Session cookie in the requests if that's what you wanted me to check.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue using Ruby - it turns out that on Windows 7 the Accept-Language request header send by IE mysteriously changes case between AJAX and normal requests....

i.e.
Normal Request: 'en-au', 
AJAX Request: 'en-AU'

This tripped up the session hijacking test in the rack-protection gem, clearing the session and causing me troubles......

IEEEEEEEEEEEEEE